# C++ Length of char* does not make sense?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I encounter this problem twice today, and I don't know where is the bug nor how to fix it.

```
#include <string.h>

char *str1 = "ab";
int length = strlen(str1);
char *str2 = new char[length + 1];
```

So when I test it with a few more lines:

```
cout << "Length of str1 = " << strlen(str1) << "\n";
cout << "Value of int length = " << length << "\n";
cout << "Length of str2 = " << strlen(str2) << "\n";
```

It gives me:

Length of str1 = 2

Value of int length = 2

Length of str2 = 48

I don't understand, 2 + 1 should be 3. The Length of str2 does not match what I initialize it.
How can I fix this, please help, thanks.

Comment: Since this is C++ and not C, you'll be more productive if you use `std::string`. No need to worry about null terminators or anything, just use strings as you would naturally. For example, your follow-up comment question has a simple answer in the form of [`substr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/substr). With C strings, you have to allocate enough memory for the new copy, use something like `memcpy` with an appropriate pointer, null-terminate the new copy (making sure you allocated that as well), then remembering to free the memory later, even with an exception or similar

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I has just switched back from C++/CLI to C++ and it is totally different.

Comment: `char *str1 = "ab";` is invalid, but may compile with not-quite-up-to-date compilers. With standard C++ you have to write `char const* str1= "ab";`, or equivalent.

Comment: looks like I need to update my book lol :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Length of C string depends on the content of the string, not on the memory allocated to the string's content. If you would like to get the correct length, you must copy the content of the original into the destination string, like this:

```
char *str1 = "ab";
int length = strlen(str1);
char *str2 = new char[length + 1];
strcpy(str2, str1);
```

What you have now is *undefined behavior*, when `strlen` passes the end of the allocated `str2` in search for null terminator, and stops only 48 bytes later, deep into memory that has not been allocated to `str2` variable.

> I need to copy only part of str1 for example, str1 = "Hello World", and I need to copy from index = 4 to index = 7

Use [`memcpy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcpy), and null-terminate the string after that:

```
char *str = "Hello, world!";
int start = 4;
int end = 7;
int len = end-start+1;
char *str2 = new char[len+1];
memcpy(str2, str1+start, len);
str2[len] = '\0';
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to copy only part of str1 for example, str1 = "Hello World", and I need to copy from index = 4 to index = 7, how would I do that?

Comment: Use `strncpy` to copy a piece of limited length.

Comment: @PaulKienitz No, that's incorrect. `strncpy` is for fixed-length strings. It fills the rest of the bytes of the block with zeros, and it does not null-terminate the string if the original is longer than the destination (which is very bad). The function that should be used is `strlcpy`, but it is non-standard.

Comment: `strncpy(str2, str1 + 4, 4)` will work just fine in this case, if str2 is four bytes or more.  (Assuming that "to index = 7" is meant inclusively.)  If str2 needs to be nul-terminated, just go `str2[4] = '\0\;`.

Answer (score 4):

The `strlen` function does not measure the size of a char array like `str2`.  It measures the offset of the first byte equal to `'\0'`.  Since the array is uninitialized, that might be anywhere in the memory you're not usnig after the array's end.